# Total angular velocity (Kerr metric)

Tags: angular-velocity, kerr-metric

I have a problem with the kerr metric and the "rotating spacetime" in the ergosphere. How can i calculate the angular velocity $\omega$ of an object in the ergosphere (which flys from infinity into the ergosphere) with angular velocity $\omega_{initial}$ before entering the ergosphere? 
So how does the ergosphere changes the angular velocity?

Comment: I'm a little surprised to see votes to close as homework. I think an answer describing the basic principles of the calculation seems perfectly reasonable.